# PHP undefined index in $_SESSION var

Tags: php

I 'm designing a Treasure hunt kind of online quiz.Totally there are 20 files namely `1.php , 2.php..10.php` .

Only if the player answers the question on the current page he must be redirected to next page ,but in my case if the player modifies the URL he can view the next question.

In order to prevent this i created 
`$_SESSION['active']` to store the level user has reached which is updated as soon as user answers one question.

on the next page while comparing the `$_SESSION['active']` with question number it is throwing error

> Undefined index: active .

Should i need to pass the var as $get..??

code of first page after right answer:

```
$_SESSION['active'][] = 2;
<script> window.location= "http//localhost/TH/third' </script>
```

code of second page at the start:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['active']<2)
{
   die("cant access");
}
else{}
```

Comment: i might attempt to read this if you format it properly

Comment: $_SESSION['active'] = value_for_answered_page; or $_SESSION['active'] = 2;

Answer (score 0):

upon completion of your first page, the value in your session is:

```
$_SESSION['active'][] = 2;
```

or:

```
$_SESSION['active'][0] = 2;
```

not

```
$_SESSION['active'] = 2;
```